# Undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when trying to pull value from hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby, and for the most part it's starting to make sense, but then I came across this problem.

I searched for a user using:

```
user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
```

I can do `user.inspect` and it displays as:

```
#<User id: 1, username: "test_user", first_name: "test", last_name: "user">
```

However, when I try to do:

```
user[:id]
```

I get:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I overlooking?

Here is the user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Validations
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :presence => true
  validates :username, :uniqueness => {:allow_blank => true}

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  default_fields = [:username, :first_name, :last_name]
  attr_accessible *default_fields

  # Instance Methods
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Additionally, if I do:

```
user.to_s
```

it results in:

```
#<User:0x007fdad09717f8>
```

Which further leads me to believe that it's not nil, but yet I can't reference the hash values.

Comment: Please show us what the `User` class is defined as, as well as the stack trace for that error you're displaying.

Comment: strange thing is that it seems to work within an .html.erb file, but the place that I'm trying to get it to work in is a .builder template file

Comment: Then it would be interesting to look at your .builder file, too. The same variable cannot be nil and not nil at the same time, you know. Then either you change it between your call to `user.to_s` and call to `user[:id]`, or your probably check for `to_s` and `[:id]` in different places. So if you show us your .builder file **WITH** your `to_s` inserted where you insert it, we may help.

Comment: @NIA thanks for having me look at the builder file.   While I was removing the extra stuff to create a minimal example file that reproduced the issue I was able to identify that an entry in the database had 'user_id' set to null; thus resulting in an actual 'nil' object about 50 iterations into a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first sentence

```
user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
```

returned a null object, so you need to test this in order to avoid the exception:

```
if( ! user.nil? )
# code with user[:id]    
end
```

Comment: If user was null, then why can I execute user.inspect without an exception and have it show the contents of the user hash?

Comment: Nil class can respond to a set of methods, like nil?, but not [] because is not defined. Check the api doc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html

Answer (score 0):

So the problem turns out not to be related to code, but to data in a Database table that I was using to get the 'user_id' value.   Thats what I get for trusting that someone else would have written proper validations on all the models in the project.

Thats everyone for helping me resolve this, if I hadn't needed to create a minimum example that reproduced the issue I never would have stumbled across the bad entry in the database.

So to use [Miguel Prz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546205/miguel-prz) Idea I ended up doing this:

```
user.nil? ? '' : user[:id]
```

This is further proof why I should never trust anyone else's work :)

Comment: Also note that **unsaved** records always have an `id` of nil too, until they are saved. So `nil` id may come not only from corrupted database, but also simply from an unsaved object. In this case you, of course, have to save all your *newly created* objects before serializing them into xml.